# Shinyapps deployment not working while works on local computer

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following app that runs fine in my computer, however, it throws an error while deploying on the shinyapps:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(rCharts)
library(DT)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(shinyapps)
# dataset <- ntctidecombined

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Seattle Society fund raise"),

  # Sidebar with a slider 
  sidebarLayout(position="left",
                sidebarPanel( 

                ),
                mainPanel(
                  #       plotOutput('plot', height="700px"))

                  tabsetPanel(
                    tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot", width = "500px", height = "600px")),
                    tabPanel("Donors / Ticket buyers", tableOutput("donors")),
                    tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table"))
                  ))

  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(rCharts)
library(DT)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(shinyapps)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  #dataset <- load("ntctidecombined.Rda")
  dataset <- read.csv("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9267938/Testspreadsheet.csv")

  dataset1 <- dataset %>% group_by(Category) %>% summarize(Sum = sum(Amount))

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    dataset2 <- dataset1

  p1 <- ggplot(dataset1, aes(x = Category, y = Sum, fill = Category)) + 
  geom_bar(stat= "identity") + ylab("Total Amount (dollars)") +
  geom_text(aes(Category, Sum, label = Sum, vjust = -1.5)) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,10000))
  p1  

  })

   output$table <- renderTable(dataset1)
   output$donors <- renderTable(dataset)

})
```

When I checked the logs in shinyapps I found that I got error as follows:

`Error in file(file, "rt") : https:// URLs are not supported`.

I am trying to use the file that is on the dropbox so I want to use that file to automatically update the graphs and statistics. What is the best way to use data from web ?

Comment: Starting at `?read.csv` and following the link to `?url` leads me to this: "Note that the https:// URL scheme is not supported except on Windows.".

Comment: The documentation continues on to suggest using either `download.file` or the **RCurl** package.

Comment: Thank you joran for your helpful suggestions. I haven't used R in linux machine so that might be the issue.

Comment: You might also look at **httr** which is a Hadley package that wraps a lot of what **RCurl** does.

Comment: Joran: Actually I did end up using `httr` package and seems to work seamlessly. Thank you. The application is working https://jdevkota.shinyapps.io/seattle/

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
dataset <- read.csv("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9267938/Testspreadsheet.csv")
```

with

```
library(RCurl)
data <- getURL("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9267938/Testspreadsheet.csv")
dataset <- read.csv(text = data )
```

should work.

or in one line

```
dataset  <- read.csv(text=getURL("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9267938/Testspreadsheet.csv"))
```

Answer (score -2):

Where the URL passed to GetURL for dropbox files must be

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/<string for user's file.csv>
```

e.g. `/u/9267938/File.csv`

Comment: This is **not** a link-only answer.